# Is there such a thing in English as "other payment for use of land" that is not, in the broad sense, "rent"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology

I ask this as an inquiry into the validity of the logic behind the currently accepted answer to [Do you still pay 10x the dice when getting the chance card that takes you to the nearest utility if the property is mortgaged?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/do-you-still-pay-10x-the-dice-when-getting-the-chance-card-that-takes-you-to-the). The argument is made that such a concept exists, which I challenged in another answer.  Does anyone know of any antecedents for such an interpretation, and in particular if they date to before World War 2?

Comment: If my electric company is bankrupt, I still have to pay for electricity if I use it. A bankrupt electric company probably isn't going to shut off service to all its customers.

Comment: @PeterShor: That would seem to be fundamental to the distinction between "real" property and "other" property. If the electric company is bankrupt (or otherwise mortgaged), the payment would go to the holder of the mortgage rather than to the holder of the real property.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - In the US the payment would go to the "receiver", who was appointed by the court to manage the bankruptcy.  He would determine how much goes to the creditors and how much is spent on current operations.

Comment: There is always "lease", of course.

Comment: What does bankruptcy have to do with this?  You can be the bankrupt holder of an unmortgaged property or the solvent holder of mortgaged property.

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a language question to me, since it asks about a concept.

Answer (score 1):

There still exists, in legalese, a term which means "right to extract value from the land" without conveying any right or title to the land itself¹.

From [Duhaime's Law Dictionary](http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/P/ProfitPrendre.aspx), for example:

> **Profit à Prendre**:
>   A [right] which resembles an easement and which allows the holder to enter the land of another and to take some natural produce such as mineral deposits, fish or game, timber, crops or pasture.

That is, you are permitted to *profit* from the land, without *owning* it.

This is the right you're paying for when, eg, you purchase a fishing or hunting license from the state or department of parks (some such licenses directly employ this bit of legalese, as a term of art).

¹ <sub>I learned of this term while researching the [related question about "pond lords"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/189327/55623).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe would be more like a [**toll**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/toll):

> a ​small ​amount of ​money that you have to ​pay to use a ​road, ​cross a ​bridge, etc. (-- Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

The money is paid as a fee for passage *across* the property, which seems relevant to the board game in question. This usage dates from the 15th Century, according to [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=toll&searchmode=none).

(**Edit** to add a nod to the modern usage relating to utilities, particularly [telephony](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toll+call)).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a toll, as JHCL said, or a levy, rate, charge or fee. If it's going across land, and the payment is for such, 'toll' would be the best choice. If it is for a service provided, a 'fee' may be preferable. A 'levy' or 'rate' suggests more of a tax, though it could also be a charge.